# Missing Parenthesis Error Using Order By and Case Switching in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a query in Oracle that uses case switching for ORDER BY. The code is below:

```
SELECT Students.ID, (CASE WHEN Grade <8 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 
Students.Name END CASE), Students.Marks, Grades.Grade 
FROM Students LEFT JOIN Grades ON Students.Marks >= Grades.Min_Mark 
AND Students.Marks <= Grades.Max_Mark 
ORDER BY(
    (
        CASE WHEN
        Grade <8 THEN Grade
        END
    )ASC + (
        CASE WHEN
        Grade >=8 THEN Grade, Name 
        END
     )DESC
    );
```

However, I get an error message that says 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis '. Any thoughts as to what I could be doing wrong? I really don't see any non-matching parenthesis.

Comment: If you're getting an `ORA-00907` error it's seems likely that you're not using MySQL. That's an Oracle error.

Comment: In your select clause, the word case after the word end looks problematic.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. My IDE had switched over to Oracle and I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the First paréntesis before "by"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Grade < 8 THEN Grade END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN Grade >= 8 THEN Grade END) DESC,
         Name
```

You have at least three errors:

- An `ORDER BY` key can have only one `ASC` or `DESC`, and it is at the end of the key expression.
- The separator for the keys is a comma, but not in the `CASE`.
- A `CASE` *expression* can return only one value.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by something as defined in a CASE, but you can't have multiple choices regarding ascending or descending. It appears you're going to need to pull in your data for grade < 8 and grade >= 8 separately, order them as you wish, and then union them together:

```
SELECT Students.ID,
       'NULL' AS STUDENT_NAME,
       Students.Marks,
       Grades.Grade 
  FROM Students
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Grades
    ON Students.Marks >= Grades.Min_Mark AND
       Students.Marks <= Grades.Max_Mark
  WHERE GRADE < 8
  ORDER BY GRADE ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT Students.ID,
       Students.Name AS STUDENT_NAME,
       Students.Marks,
       Grades.Grade 
  FROM Students
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Grades
    ON Students.Marks >= Grades.Min_Mark AND
       Students.Marks <= Grades.Max_Mark
  WHERE GRADE < 8
  ORDER BY GRADE || NAME DESC;
```

Best of luck.